# Jobs not executed in circle ci workflow

Tags: circleci

I'm trying to cascade a series of tasking using the workflow syntax with circle ci. For some reason, only the build job seems to run - but my other jobs do not.

```
version: 2
jobs:
build:
docker:
  - image: circleci/node:latest
steps:
    - checkout
    - restore_cache:
        keys:
            - sfdx-version-41-local
    - run:
        name: Install SFDX
        command: pwd
    - save_cache:
        key: sfdx-version-41-local
        paths:
            - node_modules
auth:   
    steps:
    - run:
        name: Authenticate
        command: ls -a
validate:
    steps:
    - run:
        name: Validate
        command:  mkdir whocares
clean:
    steps:
    - run:
        name: Remove Server Key
        when: always
        command: pwd

workflows:
 version: 2
 authenticate-and-deploy:
   jobs:
     - build
     - auth
     - validate
     - clean
```

Ideally, I want to make sure each step finishes with a non zero exit code before moving to next step. But I'm not sure the the subsequent steps after build are not being executed.

Thanks,

Comment: There's two issues here. 1) Your Workflows confis is not correct. Each job needs to have a require filter designating which other jobs it requires to finish first. 2) I don't see the point of having multiple jobs here. Unless any of the jobs is run in parallel or branch specific, you're actually slowing the build down here.

Let me know if you still want to stick with Workflows/multiple jobs are not and I'll provide an updated config that should work.

Comment: Hi @FelicianoTech. Yes - eventually i want to build it out for multiple branches, Such that, a PR on a particular branch will build for that environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you really wants all of these jobs for some reason, the Workflows config is missing requirements and each job is missing its executor. I also fixed indenting. You can do this:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:latest
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - sfdx-version-41-local
      - run:
          name: Install SFDX
          command: pwd
      - save_cache:
          key: sfdx-version-41-local
          paths:
            - node_modules
  auth:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:latest
    steps:
      - run:
          name: Authenticate
          command: ls -a
  validate:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:latest
    steps:
      - run:
          name: Validate
          command:  mkdir whocares
  clean:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:latest
    steps:
      - run:
          name: Remove Server Key
          when: always
          command: pwd

workflows:
  version: 2
  authenticate-and-deploy:
    jobs:
      - build
      - auth:
          requires: build
      - validate:
          requires: auth
      - clean:
          requires: validate
```

Comment: I see your point. What I was able to do instead was use a job definition alias to lessen the amount of extra steps I needed.

Answer (score 0):

```html
        Here is what I ended up doing:


    job-definition: &jobdef
    docker:
        - image: circleci/openjdk:latest-node-browsers
    steps:
        - checkout
        - restore_cache:
            keys:
                - sfdx-6.8.2-local
        - run: 
            name: Print branch
            command: |
                echo $CIRCLE_BRANCH
                if [[$CIRCLE_BRANCH == 'master']]; 
                    then
                        echo "master"; 
                    else 
                        echo "notMaster"; 
                fi

        - save_cache:
            key: sfdx-6.8.2-local
            paths: 
                - node_modules
        - run:
            name: "Validate Build"
            command: |
                #node_modules/sfdx-cli/bin/run force:mdapi:deploy -d src/ -u $USERNAME -c --testlevel RunLocalTests
                echo CIRCLE_BRANCH
        - run: 
            name: Push to Codecov.io
            command: |
                cp ~/tests/apex/test-result-codecoverage.json .
                bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
        - store_artifacts:
            path: ~/tests
        - store_test_results:
            path: ~/tests

    version: 2
jobs:
  static-analysis:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/openjdk:latest
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          keys: 
            - pmd-v6.0.1
      - run:
          name: Install PMD
          command: |
              if [ ! -d pmd-bin-6.0.1 ]; then
                  curl -L "https://github.com/pmd/pmd/releases/download/pmd_releases/6.0.1/pmd-bin-6.0.1.zip" -o pmd-bin-6.0.1.zip
                  unzip pmd-bin-6.0.1.zip
                  rm pmd-bin-6.0.1.zip
              fi
      - save_cache:
          key: pmd-v6.0.1
          paths: 
              - pmd-bin-6.0.1
      - run: 
          name: Run Static Analysis
          command: |
              pmd-bin-6.0.1/bin/run.sh pmd -d ./src/ -R $RULESET -f text -l apex -r static-analysis.txt -no-cache
      - store_artifacts:
          path: static-analysis.txt
  build-enterprise:
     <<: *jobdef
     environment:
        SCRATCH_DEF: workspace-scratch-def.json
        URL: https://login.salesforce.com
        NAME: $PROD_USERNAME
  build-developer: 
     <<: *jobdef
     environment:
        SCRATCH_DEF: developer.json
        URL: https://test.salesforce.com
        NAME: $EVANDEV_USERNAME
              workflows:
  version: 2
  test_and_static:
    jobs:
      - build-enterprise
      #- build-developer
      #- static-analysis
```

Two other thing I'm trying to do:
1. paramterize the build 
2. run build on a PR